# how do I remove end of url in wordpress .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Google crawler mistakenly adds a wrong string of my domain to the end of every link in my site :(
For example: `www.mydomain.com/folder/www.mydmain.com` (as you can see the domain that adds to end of the link is not my original domain name).

it happens in many pages and what I thought to do is to create 301 redirect with 
the correct URL removing the extra `www.mydmain.com` in the end of the URL.

I've tried several solutions that were offered here but with no success. 
How can I remove the extra string at the end of the url in `.htaccess`?

Thanks!
Lior

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect in htaccess to remove the trailing part (www.domain.com) from your urls.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)/www\.domain\.com$ /$1/
```